# iOS Push Notification Alert Button

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, alert

I am using GCM as an intermediary to APNS.  What's the corresponding GCM key to `action-loc-key` in APNS.  I am looking at the GCM [document](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) here but can't find it.  Essentially, I like to change the default button title from "Open" to another title.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely familiar with APNS but if I understand it's description from the [APNS docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html):

> If a string is specified, the system displays an alert that includes the Close and View buttons. The string is used as a key to get a localized string in the current localization **to use for the right button’s title instead of “View”**.

It's like the **OK/Confirm button** on [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)s at the Notification Bar. If so, then it seems you are looking at GCM in a different way. As per the [GCM docs](http://www.androiddocs.com/google/gcm/gcm.html):

> It does not provide any built-in user interface or other handling for message data. **GCM simply passes raw message data** received straight to the Android application, which has full control of how to handle it.

When in Android, the `Notification`s UI depends entirely on the dev.